# Weird file on desktop

Tags: files

I just installed for the first time a week ago. Today right after I booted up a strange file named `sedFwx18k` appeared on my desktop. I ran stat `sedFwx18k` in the terminal and it said `No such file or directory.`

Should I be worried my computer has a virus?

If anyone could help out I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Browser  start-tor-browser.desktop

Comment: Looks like it was from starting Tor.

Comment: Could my Tor browser be compromised?

Answer (score 0):

The command `sed` creates temp files when you run it in with the `-i` command. That said, they look like this e.g. `sedyp5j4K` however how you managed to keep the file around after the command ran through is questionable since it is usually removed by itself.

Just remove the file:

```
find ~/ -name sedFwx18k -delete
```